# How do I capture output after fabric exception

Tags: python, fabric

I'm using fabric to run a command on one server against another server. Specifically, I'm running a SQL query through the psql command line.

The fabric run() function is throwing a SystemExit exception which I can catch.

If I go to the server and run the psql command directly I am told:

```
psql: could not connect to server: Connection timed out
    Is the server running on host "xyz.example.com" (10.16.16.66) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

So, I know that the command is not working but what I want is to get that text under psql so my code can be explicit about the problem.

I think that the fabric code is fine because if I change the psql command so it executes on the same server but against a different database, I get no exception and the expected answer. So the problem is that the server I'm running psql on cannot communicate with one of the database servers.

Is it possible to get the results of the psql command through fabric after fabric throwsd the SystemExit exeption?

For reference, here's the sample code:

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import local, settings, abort, run, cd, execute, env
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm

import sys
import os

def test():
    try:
        count = run('psql blah blah blah',timeout=60)
        print('count: {}'.format(count))
    except Exception,ex:
        print('====> Exception type: %s' % ex.__class__)
        print('====> Exception: %s' % ex)
    except SystemExit,ex:
        print('====> Exception type: %s' % ex.__class__)
        print('====> Exception: %s' % ex)

def go():
    print "Working"
    env.host_string = "jobs0.onshift.com"
    execute(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [settings context manager](http://docs.fabfile.org/en/latest/api/core/context_managers.html#fabric.context_managers.settings) module in the fabric docs, and the [succeeded and failed properties](http://fabric.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/core/operations.html#fabric.operations.run) on the object returned by `run`

```
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.context_managers import settings

def test():
    with settings(warn_only = True):
        res = run('psql blah blah blah', timeout = 60)
        if res.succeeded:
            print('count: {}'.format(res))

def go():
    print "Working"
    execute(test, hosts = ["jobs0.onshift.com"])
```